# Not Found @types/react-bootstrap-table2-editor

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react-bootstrap-table2, but i can't install for react-bootstrap-table2-editor typescript

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-bootstrap-table2-editor'. 'node_modules/react-bootstrap-table2-editor/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-bootstrap-table2-editor` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-bootstrap-table2-editor';`ts(7016)
```

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: How do you ref the types file? Or have you tried to run `npm install @types/react-bootstrap-table2-editor` like it is written in the error hint?

Comment: @KargWare there is no `@types/react-bootstrap-table2-editor` the moment i checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `npm install @types/react-bootstrap-table-next`

These aren't official types so they might not work that well.

Another option is to add `// @ts-ignore` above your import. This will mean no typescript support for that package but no error either